# RC circuit intuition

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, capacitance

How to intuitively guess the output waveform of a rc differentiator to a ramp input? I know it will be a constant value if RC is very small but that's from calculation. How can I intuitively guess it? 
And if possible are there any books which help in developing intuition regarding rc circuits? I have an interview coming up with An analog design company .

Comment: Hint: it's a differentiator.

Comment: its a differentiator i know and thats obvious from the differential equation. Can we somehow predict the output waveform in a physical sense? without solving the diff equation?

Comment: Current or voltage input? Current or voltage output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect a fixed voltage at the input, current will flow through the capacitor and then through the resistor, with a resulting voltage drop across the resistor, which is also your output voltage.  But the capacitor is charging, and as it does, it opposes the input voltage, so the current decreases.  This shows up as a decreasing voltage across the output resistor.

And you are the guy with your hand on the voltage control at the input. And you see the output decreasing, so you turn the voltage up, so that your applied voltage is larger than that charge across the capacitor.  More current flows, the voltage at the output goes up again.  But then the capacitor charges some more.  So you raise the input voltage some more...

There's a balance between the output voltage wanting to fall off, and you continuously raising the input voltage to try to keep the output  where it is.   And you, continuously raising the input voltage...that's the ramp.

Big capacitor? It charges slowly, and you don't have to "chase it" by raising the input so fast.  Big resistor? Less current flow and thus less through the capacitor (from their point of view they are in series) and again the cap doesn't charge so fast.   For smaller value parts, the reverse will be true.

Comment: That's a good way to understand! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A differential is the mathematical expression for the rate of change. If the ramp rises with a constant slope rate the change will always be the same and therefore the output of a differentiator is a constant value when a ramp is present at the input.

Comment: I know that but why does it occur physically?